# MS Access: select maximum column value of a table

Tags: ms-access, vba

In my microsoft access database name is DBMS.accdb and I have an employee table and one of the column of the table is salary. I have created a form and on form load I want to get the max salary of the table and do some calculation and then set the value in a text box(total_salary) of the form. I want something like this

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim salary As Number

    salary = "SELECT MAX([EMP (staff) Salary]) FROM Employee"
    salary = salary + (1000 / 23)
    total_salary.Value = salary
End Sub
```

I tried several way using the help from internet but it is not working. I get some error every time.

How can I do this?

Comment: are you asking for the correct syntax to write the sql or do you want to know about how to run sql from within vba?

Comment: I guess I need both. I need to know how to implement the above concept on form load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the maximum you could use the `DLookup` function instead of writing an actual SQL-Statement:

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim salary As Double
    salary = DLookup("MAX(Salary)", "Employee")
    salary = salary + (1000 / 23)
    total_salary.Value = salary
End Sub
```

or via standrad sql

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim salary As Double
    salary = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Employee")(0)
    salary = salary + (1000 / 23)
    total_salary.Value = salary
End Sub
```

Comment: Its working. But could you also show it by using sql query like 'SELECT MAX([EMP (staff) Salary]) FROM Employee'

Comment: @user1670773 there you go.

Comment: This is working perfectly. But I don't understand why I need (0).

Comment: because in theory the recordset returns you a list/collection/array of fields, you/I want to use only the first one (which in this case is the only one too) - (0) acceses the first element of the returned fields.

Comment: Just curious, Would not using `DMax` instead of `DLookup` be more efficient? How about `salary` coping with `NULL`?

Comment: I have no idea wether one or the other is more efficient, i would guess that DMax just wraps the DLookUp field in a `MAX` as well ;) Regarding NULL: does not appear to be of any concern here - salary can not be null, would not make sense. I think it is better to give him the more general solution, hence the sql-example as well.